# How to install Source Safe Plug in the Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I am working on VS 2008 Environment. I have Visual Source Safe version 8.0.

From my Visual Studio 2008 Environment, I am not able to Check-In or Check-Out. Project is opening as Temporarily Source Safe not available.

I couldnt see Source Safe Option on File ->. I went to Tools -> Options - Source Control -> Plug-in Selection ->  NONE.

[image]
How to install Source Safe Plug in the Visual Studio 2008 ?

Comment: Can you run SSEXP.exe on your PC. That will confirm it's installed and DLLs registered etc.

Comment: thanks.. i will do that..

Comment: wtf are you still using Visual SourceSafe!! It was bad enough using it 10 years ago

Comment: Our team is using VSS.. and so i have to ..!! Eventually we are migrating to TFS .., that project is going on..

Comment: Anyways.. i will uninstall and reinstall the VSS that will solve my issue